# Assign local method variable to class pointer

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm changing some code to deal with a change in the signature of some functions which are being called by it. The original code looks something like (this is only illustrative):

```
int main()
{
   TestClassA instance;
   instance.MethodA();
   instance.MethodB();
   // do other stuff with instance
}

class TestClassA
{
   void MethodA ()
   {
       UList* aList = NULL;
       getListOfStuff(aList);
       // do some stuff
       fList = aList;
   }
   void MethodB ()
   {
       //do something with fList
   }
   UList* fList;
}

struct Ulist
{
   int value;
   std::vector<Ulist> components;
}

getListOfStuff(UList* aList)
{
   aList = new UList();
   PopulateOriginal(aList);
}
```

The signature of getListOfStuff has now changed (the change is beyond my control) to:

```
getListOfStuff(UList& aList)
{
   aList=PopulateNewVersion();
}
```

Seems I wasn't clear about what I was asking, so to clarify...what I am asking is how to call the new version of the method `getListOfStuff` and safely store the returned data from it (the `aList` parameter) in a raw pointer field `fList`, which can then be accessed from `MethodB` later on.

Following on from @GuillaumeGris answer below, would the following work? (The bit I'm unsure about is whether the assignment within the new `getListOfStuff` affects whether `fList` is still pointing to valid data after `MethodA` has exited.)

```
void MethodA ()
{
   UList* aList = new UList();
   getListOfStuff(*aList);
   // do some stuff
   fList = aList;
}
```

Comment: In your _illustrative_ code, the function `main()` has a return type of void. It should have a return type of `int`

Comment: does `// do some stuff` have any conditions that would allow the constructor to exit without assigning `fList = aList`?

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer The code was just supposed to provide a notional framework to illustrate the actual issue. The real code is embedded far down in other classes. But yes, noted - it should be `int`.

Comment: @user4581301 `\\do something' never returns from `MethodA` early (it's just a general method rather than a constructor) - the assignment to `fList` always takes place before the call returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an explicit heap allocation (`new`).

```
class TestClassA
{
   void MethodA ()
   {
       // Clear components
       fList.components.clear();

       getListOfStuff(fList);
   }
   UList fList;
}
```

If fList is optional, I would recommend the use of a `std::unique_ptr`

```
class TestClassA
{
   void MethodA ()
   {
       if (!fList)
           fList = std::make_unique<Ulist>();
       else
       {
           // Clear components
           fList->components.clear();
       }

       getListOfStuff(*fList);
   }
   std::unique_ptr<UList> fList;
}
```

Comment: The second option (when you pass in the pointer with a dereference) was one which I had considered too, but I was unsure whether the returned object would be validly allocated on the heap, since it is re-assigned within `getListOfStuff`. I actually cannot change the type of `fList` since, in reality, it is in a base class of `TestClassA` which it will be difficult to change. For this, I presume it is still OK to do something like `if (!fList) { fList = new UList(); getListOfStuff(*fList); }` ?